# Using jQuery, trying to retrieve an image src value, when a nearest radio button is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have a page that contains numerous divs like what is shown below, it is a page of color swatches, ie thumb size images.

what i'm trying to do is, when the user clicks on the radio button, get the source value of the image that is contained in the label element and then replace the main product image with it. but my code keeps returning the value as undefined. i've tried several variations on the code below, i've tried jQ's closest(), find(), next() and also prop("src") and attr().

```
('.swatches-radio-btn').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    var currImg = $(this).closest('label img').prop( "src" ); //not working
    alert(currImg); //returns undefined
    $('#productMainImage img').prop('src', currImg);
})
})
```

the mark-up is this,

```
<div id="productMainImage">
<img src="images/PP_watercress87.jpg" alt="Pepper Pot Silk" />
</div>

<div class="threads-swatch-wrapper">
<input type="radio" name="id[10]" value="129" id="attrib-10-129" class="swatches-radio-btn" />
<label class="attribsRadioButton thread-opts" for="attrib-10-129">Artichoke <br />
    <img src="images/attributes/PP_artichoke77.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="320" />
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    var currImg = $(this.labels[0]).find('img').prop('src');
    $('#productMainImage img').prop('src', currImg);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nP7Td/).

Or, if you're working with a browser that doesn't implement the `labels` property of the `HTMLInputElement`, you could instead use:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    var currImg = $(this).closest('div').find('label img').prop('src');
    $('#productMainImage img').prop('src', currImg);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nP7Td/1/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`labels` (in the `HTMLInputElement` reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: yeah on the IE i tried it on, the first one did not work but the second one did, thanks much

Answer (score 1):

`.closest` searches up the tree whilst `.find` searches down. Use find instead.

Answer (score 1):

This might work: `var currImg = $(this).next('label').children('img').prop( "src" );`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this -

```
$('.swatches-radio-btn').click(function(){
   var currImg = $(this).next().find('img').attr('src');
   $('#productMainImage img').attr('src', currImg);
});
```

**WORKING DEMO** - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/xsdIj

Comment: @TopTomato glad I could help. You can accept one but still up vote multiple answers you find work well.